# Performing a query for specific user-types in Firebase/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a data structure in firebase that looks something like this:

[image: My Database Structure]

Some users are "trucks", others are "users"

A table in my app will display to the "users" a list of all of the names of "trucks" in the database, which I'm planning on populating from an array of "truck" names.

basically,

```
for each user in listOfUsers{
     if userType = "truck"{

         //append nameValue to array truckNames

     }
}
```

How would I structure an observeEventType style query to assemble this data?  So far I have only performed relatively simple queries, this is my first that needs to check 2 conditions within a child at once.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not really sure why you need two conditions here. If you just want to select trucks (an incredibly uncommon name for a user type btw) you'd just `ref.queryOrderedByChild("userType").queryEqualToValue("truck")` as described in the [Firebase guide on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries).

Comment: If you *do* need multiple conditions, you will either have to merge the values into a single property or (if that's not possible) restructure the data to allow the lookup you need. See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Thanks for the resource, Frank!